# For $x \sim $ exp

Tags: probability

$$E[X^2\mid X>1] = E[(X +1)^2]$$

I understand that $P(X>s+t \mid X>s)=P (X>t)$, however, I don't know how the statement above should be immediately obvious?

Comment: Does the above hold for every $g(X)$, i.e. $E[g(X)|X>1]=E[g(X+1)]$?

Answer (score 1):

Write it as an integral and use a change of variables $t\mapsto t+1$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\Pr(X-s>t \mid X>s) = \Pr(X>t).
$$

So the conditional distribution of $X-s$ given that event, is the same as the distribution of $X$.

Consequently $\mathbb K(X-s\mid X>s)$ must be the same as $\mathbb K(X)$, where "$\mathbb K(\bullet)$" is any quantity that depends only on the probability distribution of the random variable called "$\bullet$".

So that's true in particular when $s=1$ and $\mathbb K(V) = \mathbb E((V-1)^2)$ and $V=X+1$.